# Is there any tool that can replicate smart contracts found on explorers?

Tags: contract-deployment

A tool that can replicate smart contracts on different EVM-compatible networks without requiring the source code would be valuable for quick experimentation and testing. It would allow users to easily deploy and interact with existing contracts found on platforms like Etherscan, without the need for manual scripting or an in-depth understanding of the contract's code. This simplifies the process of trying out various contracts on test networks, facilitating exploration and analysis of different functionalities without the overhead of obtaining and adapting source code for deployment.

Is there any tool that can replicate smart contracts found on explorers?

Comment: There are tools like ganache fork, hardhat that allow operating over a deployed contract in a fake mode to simulate transactions and for testing purposes. I don't see the use for a tool to duplicate a contract without the source code. It is doable but I don't see a useful purpose.

Comment: You could replicate a service you didn't develop, with ease. But, of course, if you did develop yourself, you would have the source code and deployment scripts anyway, so in this case, you would simply use the scripts you wrote.